# How to feed LP files to the GLOP solver of or-tools?

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools

I would like to use or-tools and the [GLOP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop) solver to solve linear programming problems.

I already have another program that creates [LP files](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.0/CPLEX-format.htm) which are, as far as I know, fairly standard for defining linear programs.

Has anyone managed to pass those files directly to GLOP? What file format das GLOP understand and how do I pass them to GLOP?

Example lp file:

```
maximize 2x1 + 3x2 - x3
subject to
 x1 + x2 <= 1
 x1 + x2 + x3 <= 0
 x2 - 2x3 <= 2
bounds
 x1 free
 x2 free
 x3 free
end
```

Edit:

- I am looking for a Java solution
- `LoadLinearProgramFromModelOrRequest` seems to be the way. See [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/lp_data/model_reader/). I don't know how to use it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not API to read LP files, we did not write a good enough LP reader.
We do support reading MPS files.

Comment: can you give an example of an MPS file and how to read it with java?

Comment: and what does `LoadLinearProgramFromModelOrRequest` do? The docstring suggests it can read LP files.

Comment: This is a C++ API, not exported in Java, and it reads from a MPModelProto or MPModelRequest protobuf file. I do not think we have a java API to read MPS files. We do have a C++ binary called solve (examples/cpp/solve that can read MPS files and solve them with different solvers). Why do you need it in Java? Reading the solution will be clunky at best.

Comment: I would like to solve LPs within a larger application that is written in Java. It would be convenient to work with Java.

Comment: Why not use the java API ? https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/samples/SimpleMipProgram.java

Comment: In the future I guess I will. Currently the LP files come from another program. I would just like to see how or-tools compares with other solvers and I don't want to translate the LP files into or-tools commands just yet. Do you have a basic C++ file that reads LP files and solves them with or-tools? I don't speak C++.

Comment: From 3 answer ago: We do have a C++ binary called solve (examples/cpp/solve that can read MPS files and solve them with different solvers) and no, it does not read LP files.

Comment: @LaurentPerron I'm very interested in using MPS or LP (either is fine) files and solving optimization problems using OR tools. However, I'm not seeing any python documentation on taking a model and solving it, unless I use some type of protobuff layer in the middle. What is the preferred way to read an lp/mps file and solve the optimization problem using OR-tools without writing the whole thing in c++

Comment: Look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/model_builder/python/model_builder.py . You can import from mps, solve it, and access the solution through var_from_index.

Answer (score 1):

After scouring through the `or-tools` GitHub repo, I found that it *was* possible to read `.lp` files (**of the [`lp_solve` `.lp` file format](https://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/lp-format.htm)**, **not** the [CPLEX `.lp` file format](https://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/CPLEX-format.htm)) until March 2022 (`ortools==9.3.10497`):

Assuming you have an `lp_solve` file called `sample.lp` with the following contents:

```
min: x1 + x2;
x1 >= 1;
x2 >= 1;
x1 + x2 >= 2;
```

Running the following code:

```python
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
from ortools.model_builder.python import pywrap_model_builder_helper
from ortools.linear_solver import linear_solver_pb2

with open('sample.lp') as f:
    lp_string = f.read()

model_string = pywrap_model_builder_helper.ImportFromLpString(lp_string)
model = linear_solver_pb2.MPModelProto.FromString(model_string)
print('Model:')
print(model)

solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('GLOP')
solver.LoadModelFromProto(model)
solution = solver.Solve()

solution_response = linear_solver_pb2.MPSolutionResponse()
solver.FillSolutionResponseProto(solution_response)
print('Solution:')
print(solution_response)
```

Should result in the following output:

```python
Model:
variable {
  lower_bound: 1
  upper_bound: inf
  objective_coefficient: 1
  is_integer: false
  name: "x1"
}
variable {
  lower_bound: 1
  upper_bound: inf
  objective_coefficient: 1
  is_integer: false
  name: "x2"
}
constraint {
  var_index: 0
  var_index: 1
  coefficient: 1
  coefficient: 1
  lower_bound: 2
  upper_bound: inf
  name: "r0"
}
maximize: false
objective_offset: 0
name: ""

Solution:
status: MPSOLVER_OPTIMAL
objective_value: 2
variable_value: 1
variable_value: 1
dual_value: 0
reduced_cost: 1
reduced_cost: 1
```

The above sample was patched together based on an old revision of the [`model_builder_helper.py`](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/49b6301e1e1e231d654d79b6032e79809868a70e/ortools/model_builder/python/model_builder_helper.py#L83) script from the `or-tools` repo.

Comment: Do you have your requirements file? I'm running into differences in the library: AttributeError: module 'ortools.model_builder.python.pywrap_model_builder_helper' has no attribute 'ImportFromLpString'

I've see an instance method with a similar name, but there are enough differences that the code posted won't run even though we are posting in the same month

For example, .ImportFromLpString(lp_string) returns a bool in my code, rather than a string, so I'm unable to call linear_solver_pb2.MPModelProto.FromString(model_string) since model_string is actually a bool

Comment: @Goku `pip freeze | grep ortools` gave me `ortools==9.3.10497`

Comment: It seems all of this functionality has been removed in March: https://github.com/google/or-tools/commit/c48a7c437dbec8c7b5bf6d3361ec3d3bb179ca60 Anyway, the authors clearly didn't mean to expose or offer this functionality, so I recommend using the code I offer above as a proof of concept. BTW Laurent Perron, the author of the accepted answer here, is the creator of `ortools`, so if he says it's not supported - then it's not supported :)