# Convert string representation of a comparison formula back to formula

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here.

I have a library function that is expecting a formula object;
`solver.Add(x + y < 5)`

However my formula is dynamic and being provided from another system as a string `"x + y < 5"`

The library function doesn't not accept a string, my question is there a way to create a function that can evaluate my string and return the formula as an object? eg
`solver.Add(evaluateFormula("x + y < 5"))`
or
`solver.Add(evaluateFormula("x + y") < 5)`

Using the built in `eval()` does not work for this type of formula since that tries to execute the formula which is not what I want to do.

Here's some full sample code;

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():
    # Create the MIP solver BOP/SAT/CBC
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('BOP')

    # Sample Input Data
    req_json = {
        "Variables": [
            {
                "Name": "x",
                "Max": 10
            },
            {
                "Name": "y",
                "Max": 5
            }
        ],
        "Constraints": [
            {
                "Name": "c",
                "Formula": "x + y < 5"
            }
        ]
    }

    # Create the variables
    v = {}
    for i in range(len(req_json['Variables'])):
        v[i] = solver.IntVar(0, req_json['Variables'][i]['Max'], req_json['Variables'][i]['Name'])

    # Create the constraints
    solver.Add(v[0] + v[1] < 5)
    # solver.Add(evaluateFormula(req_json['Constraints'][0]['Formula']))

    # Maximize
    solver.Maximize(v[0] + v[1])

    # Solve
    status = solver.Solve()

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print('Solution:')
        print('Objective value =', solver.Objective().Value())
        print('x =', v[0].solution_value())
        print('y =', v[1].solution_value())
```

Comment: are x and y variables with values, or just symbols? If they are symbols I am surprised solver.Add(x + y < 5) doesn't throw any errors about x and y not being defined.

Comment: Are you expecting always `x` and `y`? If not, do you know the "variable" names?

Comment: x and y are just symbols (no values). I do know the variable names. I would also be able to provide my formulas with specific variable names so that they could already be declared in my python function.

Comment: You could use `setters` and `getters`, in unusual circumstances, you might need to use `exec(...)` too.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I'm providing the formula from another system with some authentication between systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that `x` and `y` are variables, e.g.,

```
x = solver.IntVar(0, xmax, 'x')
y = solver.IntVar(0, ymax, 'y')
```

so that when you call `solver.Add(x + y < 5)`, python will look up the names `x` and `y` and substitute them for the objects they are. That is, `IntVar + IntVar < 5`, which will be a constraint object.

When you do `eval('x + y < 5')`, it's as if you're doing `x + y < 5`, so you just need to ensure that the names `x` and `y` exist in the current scope. There are two ways of achieving that, namely

```
var = req_json['Variables'][0]

exec('{0} = IntVar(0, {1}, "{0}")'.format(var['Name'], var['Max']))   # first
locals()[var['Name']] = IntVar(0, var['Max'], var['Name'])            # second
```

The first one creates the string `'x = IntVar(0, 10, "x")'`, which it executes as a literal python statement. While the second one creates the `IntVar` programmatically and then stores it in the name `x`. `locals()['x'] = 1` is the equivalent of `x = 1`.

All in all, the solution could be

```
# You don't need to manually store the variables, as they're added in `solver.variables()`
for var in req_json['Variables']:
    name = var['Name']
    locals()[name] = solver.IntVar(0, var['Max'], name)
for constraint in req_json['Constraints']:
    solver.Add(eval(constraint['Formula']), constraint['Name'])

# However you decide what the expression is to maximise. Whether it's another key
# in your `req_json` dict, or the LHS of the constraint formula. I'll just hardcode this.
solver.Maximize(x + y)

status = solver.Solve()

if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
    print('Solution:')
    print('Objective value =', solver.Objective().Value())
    for v in solver.variables():
        print('{} = {}'.format(v.name(), v.solution_value()))
```

**THIS ASSUMES THAT `eval(constraint['Formula'])` WILL NEVER DO ANYTHING MALICIOUS**, which you say is your case. If you can't guarantee that, your other option is to parse the string manually for the variable names, operations and relations and build a safe string which can then be evaluated.

Finally, if you run this as is, you'll get an error saying

```
ValueError: Operators "<" and ">" not supported with the linear solver
```

But if you change the constraint formula to `'x + y <= 5'`, it'll work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and sample code, I was able to use this to get it working. Cheers.